# Using html <a> tag instead of LinkButton, can't access c# code-behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm tryna create an ASP.NET Empty Web application that allows users to sign up and log in to access different pages from the public. I'm currently using a masterpage that holds the navigational links, using the html  tag. However, for one of my buttons it is used to Sign Out of the user's account to redirect them back to the page where the public that isn't logged in are able to access. However, to use a code behind, it'll probably require me to use a LinkButton to access the c# code behind for my sign out code, which is

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
```

However, if I use a LinkButton it is required for me to use a  tag, which screws up my page layout (the navigational links). Is there a way I can use the  tag and still access my c# code behind to implement the codes I've pasted above?

Anyway I tried this

```
<a id="signOutBtn" onclick="signOut_Click" onserverclick="signOut_Click" runat="server">Sign Out</a>
```

but I got this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.masterpageuser_master' does not contain a definition for 'signOut_Click' and no extension method 'signOut_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.masterpageuser_master' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: try `runat="server"`: `<a runat=server" OnClick="SignOut">Sign Out</a>`

Comment: hi @KhanhTO I tried (see edit above) but it doesn't work

Comment: the error is because you don't have the `signOut_Click` function in your code behind.

Comment: do you have that function in your master page? I have posted my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Try `runat="server"`:

`<a runat="server" id="signOutBtn" onserverclick="signOut_Click">Sign Out</a>`

And in your code behind, define your function:

```
public void signOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
     Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried your method, but now when I click Sign Out, nothing happens :-( On hover it says javascript:_doPostBack('ctI00$navigationlinks$ctI00',")

Comment: Still doesn't work :-( still gettin the javascript:_doPostBack('ctI00$navigationlinks$ctI00',") when I try to click it

Comment: @user3763216: I'm not sure if `href="#"` works: `<a runat=server" onserverclick="signOut_Click" href="#">Sign Out</a>`

Comment: @user3763216: did you debug to see if the request ever hits the server?

Comment: Cool! Is the signOutBtn in __doPostBack('signOutBtn', ''); the method name in the code behind?

Comment: @user3763216: `signOutBtn` is to identity the sender (the object that fires the event).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69551/discussion-between-khanh-to-and-user3763216).

Comment: @user3763216: Is there a problem somewhere else? If the problem is not related to this code, I'd appreciate if you mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.